# Groovy: Is there a way to implement multiple inheritance while using type-checking?

Tags: groovy, multiple-inheritance, typechecking

```
@groovy.transform.TypeChecked
abstract class Entity {
    ...
    double getMass() {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

@groovy.transform.TypeChecked
abstract class Location {
    ...
    Entity[] getContent() {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

@groovy.transform.TypeChecked
abstract class Container {...}  //inherits, somehow, from both Location and Entity

@groovy.transform.TypeChecked
class Main {
    void main() {
        double x
        Container c = new Chest() //Chest extends Container
        Entity e = c
        x = e.mass
        Location l = c
        x = l.content  //Programmer error, should throw compile-time error
    }
}
```

Essentially, is there a way to achieve this, without sacrificing any of the three properties outlines in `main()`:

- Direct access to fields, even virtual fields
- Assigning to both super-classes
- Typechecking (at compile-time)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with classes. Maybe you'd wanted [traits](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Adding-Trait-to-Groovy-td5715831.html) (<strike>under discussion</strike> **update:** [available in Groovy 2.3](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.3.0/html/documentation/core-traits.html) and already rocking!) or, for a pure dynamic solution, `@Mixin`, which you'd back up with a good test suite.

My guess: `@Delegate` is your best friend here, but, as it stands, you can only store a `Chest` object in a `Container` type variable. So you'd need some interfaces.

Even if the superclass is not under your control, you can use groovy `as` operator to make it implement an interface.

First, i rewrote your classes to remove the `abstract` and add interfaces:

```
import groovy.transform.TypeChecked as TC

interface HasMass { double mass }
interface HasContent { Entity[] getContent() }

@TC class Entity implements HasMass { double mass }

@TC class Location {
    Entity[] getContent() {
        [new Entity(mass: 10.0), new Entity(mass: 20.0)] as Entity[]
    }
}
```

Note i didn't added `HasContent` to `Location`, to show the usage of `as`.

Second, comes the `Container` and `Chest`. `@Delegate` is added and it auto-inherits the interfaces of the delegates:

```
@TC 
abstract class Container {
  @Delegate Location location = new Location()
  @Delegate Entity entity = new Entity()
}


@TC class Chest extends Container { }
```

Last, it becomes type-checkable, as long as you stick to interfaces:

```
@TC class Mult {
    static main(args) {
        def x // use 'def' for flow-typing
        Container c = new Chest() //Chest extends Container
        HasMass e = c
        x = e.mass
        def l = c as HasContent

        x = l.content  //Programmer error, should throw compile-time error

        assert c.content.collect { Entity it -> it.mass } == [10.0, 20.0]
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the delegator (in this example, Container) from within the delegate, or do I need to have a variable pointing back at it?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I'm not aware of any way to get the delegator. If it were a `@Mixin` solution then maybe you could use `metaClass.owner`.